# date field weird behaviour

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a model representing a mongo document with a date field.

```
class model 
{
    ...

    [BsonElement("dateCreated")]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

I know that mongo stores values at UTC time so I use `BsonDateTimeOptions` attribute to automatically represent them at local time.

When I create a instanse of the model and store it to mongo it works as expected. But, when I receive the data from an external source (client to my service) and desirializing to my model it stores the local time.

Compiler shows same values for the 2 different instances (before inserting them on mongo) but in db the first is stored in UTC and the second in local time.

Comment: Have a look at the `Kind` property of each value before you insert it.

Comment: I just checked it. The 1st object has `Kind=Unspecified` and the deserialized `Kind=Local`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "first" and "deserialized" here, but that's going to be the root of the problem. Work out what the "unspecified" version really means...

Comment: The first is the one I create on my code and the second is the one parsed from a json request using `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<model>(body)`.

Comment: So perhaps you need to configure your BsonSerializer - I know nothing about that...

Comment: What's the value coming across in your JSON before using the mongo driver's Deserialize on it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to assign a Kind to your json parsed data before saving, whether that be local or Utc.  That will tell the mongo driver what it represents so that it doesn't incorrectly convert to another format before saving.

```
someDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(someDate, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```